# Prevent refresh on wordpress page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a custom wordpress quiz plugin which creates a quiz with a URL for example

/practice-exam/?customize_autosaved=on&customize_changeset_uuid=random-characters

I am looking to see if i can prevent users from refreshing the page when in this 'exam mode' as they go back to the beginning (but if they don't refresh everything is fine)

I am hoping there is a way to add something to the functions.php and potentially put a message saying "Opps you can't refresh the page"

But open to suggestions. Any help much appreciated!

Please see above what the issue is

Comment: **Question**: what happens if the user does not refresh the page, but open a new page (in chrome, open a new tab) with the same URL ?

Comment: I think you're saying that when a user refreshes the page, they are sent to the beginning of the quiz? And to solve this, you're trying to prevent a refresh. If so, the solution would be to fix the quiz plugin to resume where the user left off, not to prevent a refresh, since that is triggered at the browser-level, plus as Ken Lee mentioned, they could leave and come back.

Comment: The problem is - the quiz randomly generates questions, so if the user refreshes the page, they will see random questions. So i would ideally like to stop them refreshing the page to avoid this issue. But this might not be possible?

Comment: **One of the ways**: Instead of randomly generating questions in each visit, you should amend the system so that when the user first starts the quiz, it will draw a set of random questions from the pool for this particular user , but after that, the drawn set should remain the same in subsequent site visits for the same user

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do something like this, save a random value for a quiz id that has been started. Like so:

```js
localStorage.setItem('quiz_id', 1)
```

On page load check for value, if it exists then the user has already started the quiz and has reloaded or returned (after leaving), so trigger some kind of message:

```js
if(localStorage.getItem('quiz_id') != null) {
 alert("You reloaded the page.")
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to actually prevent a reload without a custom browser or browser extension. This method is also easily broken if someone deletes the local storage item.

Hopefully this is helpful!